# How can you reset CSS headings to the default sizes?

Tags: css

How can I reset the sizes of headings to the default sizes? Here's some HTML that I have:

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
```

Here's the CSS for it:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 1em 0 0.5em;
}

/*I'd like to reset that height of 16px and use the default browser height */
h2 {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

I need to override the old `h2` selector and reset the headings to the default size? I've Googled this and it said that the heading sizes were browser dependent and I don't want to hard-code the heading sizes.

This is a really basic question I know but somehow I can't wrap my head around what value I need to use to reset the height.

Comment: What's stoping you from changing that particular declaration?

Comment: So, now that I've answered and discussed and such... does your CSS define a font size on the `body`, the `html`, or on a parent element?

Answer (score 2):

According to [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/), the default `body` font size is `16px` (and this is consisent across browsers).

The [W3C recommended default stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) shows the `h2` size as `1.5 em`.

Some simple calculation brings us to `16 * 1.5 = 24px`.

So, setting your h2 `font-size` to `24px` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot set a property of an element to its default value except by not setting the property in any author style sheet. Methods suggested for this are based on misunderstandings or on some assumptions about defaults, but the defaults are browser-dependent.

Comment: What about `initial` keyword? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial

Comment: Not assumptions. Testing. The idea that defaults are browser-dependent, while valid several years ago, is quickly becoming invalid due to increased standards compliance.

Comment: @Pavlo, `initial` sets the property to its initial value as defined in CSS specifications. (For `font-size`, it is `medium`, independently of element.) Not the default value as defined by browsers. @RyanKinal, standards (specifications) do not define default values; and they are browser-dependent for a reason.

Comment: True, the [HTML4 default style sheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) is described as "informative, not normative", but it has been demonstrated that browsers stick to the defacto standard of 16px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) from the beginning and it'll normalize the heading sizes across browsers:

> Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

For example, here is a fix for the `<h1>` tag:

```
/*
 * Addresses `h1` font sizes within `section` and `article` in Firefox 4+,
 * Safari 5, and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to go back to the browser's default font-size because everyone does it a little bit differently.

When you change the font size on your h2, it will impact the size of your margins as well (since they are defined in `em`).  I suspect you are trying to modify the font-size to 16px in an attempt to match the margins of other elements that are also specified in `em`.  If this is the case, you will need to set your properties differently:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: .75em 0 0.333em; /* (1 / 1.5) 0 (.5 / 1.5) */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The default `font-size` for headers is `medium`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-size

So you would do:

```
h2 {font-size: medium;}
```

Comment: But `em` are based on the font-size of the parent element.

Comment: @RyanKinal What it has to do with `medium`?

Comment: It doesn't. It has to do with your comment.

Answer (score -2):

Probably the easiest way to have the heading font-size be set back to default is to remove the font-size declaration from the h2 element you already have, so instead of:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 1em 0 0.5em;
}
```

you will just have

```
h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.5em;
}
```

You will also want to check your style sheets for any other spots a h2 font-size might be declared. If you can't or don't want to remove the font-size delcaration you can do the following to reset the font-size for all h2 elements to default

```
h2 {
    font-size: medium !important;
}
```

The font-size of medium is the default value for all browsers and the !important at the end makes it override all other declared styles. You need to be careful using important though because it makes it much harder to determine how a style is going to cascade through the elements and/or how it is being applied.

Cheers and how this helps.

Source for default value: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

Comment: Two things: Don't link w3schools, and don't use `!important`

Comment: I can see you have put some effort into this answer, So I wont do my usual "OMG WHAT ARE YOU DOING?!?!" response, However I feel you should know that w3schools is a **horrible** resource (google can tell you why) and if you personally use it, you should stop and use MDN or other, just not w3schools. My second complaint is the use of `!important`, if you are using this to mute other rules then you have done something wrong. There are very few legitimate use cases for !important, and it should be viewed as akin to using `eval` in JavaSript. - My two cents.

Comment: @rlemon: if the goal is to get the `h2` to display at a certain size no matter what other styles are applied to it, I would say that's *exactly* what `!important` is for...

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback guys I do appreciate it. I'll explain my thoughts so you can understand my answer and choices a little more: On W3Schools - after checking it seems the biggest argument against them is they try to piggyback on the W3C's reputation as the standards org but they lay out good/decent information in an easy to read and understand format for beginners. On !important - I like to let people know what tools exist and I thought my warning about screwing up the cascading of styles was decent and got the point across that you need to use it with caution.