# How to override cascading of CSS font-size back to default on child elements (in a list)

Tags: html, css

ok, so I have a bunch of lists, some nested, and with other elements inside them.  It is for documentation.  I am using an ordered list as the parent of all, and want to make the first "line" look like a heading.  So with a large number next to the text.

```css
article ol.toc > li {
  font-size: 2em;
}
article ol.toc > li * {
  font-size: medium; /* to catch IE, but will make all headings etc. 16px */
  font-size: initial; /* this does not work in IE, and not as expected for elements like the h2 */
}
```

```html
<article>
  <ol class="toc">
    <li>
      Some title text here
      <p>a bunch of very important words that all the users will read, because documentation</p>
      <ul>
        <li>great point</li>
        <li>good point</li>
        <li>better point</li>
      </ul>
      <p>sometimes I amaze myself</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Spelling is overrated
      <h2>Why is this h2 still small</h2>
      <p>It just HTML, get over it</p>
      <p>CSS, JavaScript, PHP</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Foo
      <p>bar</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p>for reference</p>
  <h2>an h2's default size</h2>
</article>
```

Is there a way to do this without having to re-declare `font-size` for each `<ol>` child element that is not 16px? (like h2, h3, etc)

--- EDIT ---
As the accepted answer below indicates, `initial` doesn't work as I expected.
My solution is to add to the HTML markup and wrap everything inside the `<li>` with a `<div>`  the 'undo' font-size can then be applied to the `<div>` by means of any of `0.5em` or `medium` or `1rem` which effectively comes back to 1em = 16px

ex.

```css
      article ol.toc > li {
        font-size: 2em;
      }
      article ol.toc > li > * {
        font-size: 0.5em;
      }
```

```html
<article>
  <ol class="toc">
    <li>
      Some title text here
      <div>
        <p>a bunch of very important words that all the users will read, because documentation</p>
        <ul>
          <li>great point</li>
          <li>good point</li>
          <li>better point</li>
        </ul>
        <p>sometimes I amaze myself</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      Spelling is overrated
      <div>
        <h2>Why is this h2 still small</h2>
        <p>It just HTML, get over it</p>
        <p>CSS, JavaScript, PHP</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      Foo
      <div>
        <p>bar</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p>for reference</p>
  <h2>an h2's default size</h2>
</article>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong about  : `article ol.toc > li * {font-size:1rem;]` not to use it?

Comment: it would seem `1rem` and `medium` have the same results.  not what I am looking for.  I want more like an unset type value, but I don't think there is one.

Comment: 1rem is font value set on html *Supported by all modern browsers, the CSS3 rem unit allows font size and other properties to be specified against the root element, not just the parent, as is the case for the em unit.* set that initial value you refer to on html, and then use it whereever needed even if you did reset font-size on body ;) 1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem will be calculated from html font-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `font-size: initial` would work in Edge and many other browsers but that won't help you here.

The issue here is that the [initial value](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value) works differently than you might expect - it resets everything to [spec default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460949/how-can-you-reset-css-headings-to-the-default-sizes#comment18413006_13461730). As a result, a h2 being rendered small is correct.

So, probably you can point out the specific behaviours and element layout you want to have. In terms of performance: if you have lots (200+) nodes you might encounter minimal effects on using the asterisk selector as last element. Otherwise it doesn't play a role anymore as engines developed.

Comment: I fixed the css comments, it was a long day.  I guess the issue is that `initial` does not do what I thought.

Comment: I will accept this answer because it explains why `initial` doesn’t work, and the answer to my question is basically no.

Comment: EDGE is not IE (same poop, different pile)